# How to prevent duplicate entries in an Access database using c#?

Tags: database, ms-access

i have a table of MS Access which contains one column and many rows.  The value of a textbox saved to this table.  I want to prevent duplicate entries from being submitted.  For example, if I type  "ankush" in the textbox and this entry already exists in table, then I want to display a msgbox saying that this already exists in the table. using c#

Answer (score 4):

If the field is not your primary key field you can set an index on the field that contains 'ankush' and make that index unique

```
[Index=Yes(no duplicates)]
```

then the Jet DB Engine will not allow the insert and will show a default message.

I am working with an older version of Access, so your mileage may vary, but to show a custom error message you would have to first do a query for the value in the table like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(MyField)as violated FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = 'input value here'
```

Then branch in your code if violated > 0 to show your message box.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a unique key on the column.

Answer (score 0):

The focus of the question has completely changed, rendering the answer obsolete.

Comment: Adding "using c#" changes the whole focus of the question.

Comment: Doesn't mean you shouldn't still have appropriate unique indexes in your back end tables, though.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: if you'd said "unique constraints" then I would have agreed: you don't have to use an index to implement a unique constraint in ACE/Jet. See my answer in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what @Gary.Ray has suggested: if your table has multiple candidate keys ("If the field is not your primary key...") then the failure message the ACE/Jet engine returns unhelpfully does not tell you which key was violated:

> The changes you requested to the table
>   were not successful because they would
>   create duplicate values in the index,
>   primary key, or relationship.  Change
>   the data in the field or fields that
>   contain duplicate data, remove the
>   index, or redefine the index to permit
>   duplicate entries and try again.

Happily, there is more than one way to implement a key and using a `CHECK` constraint has the advantage of returning the name of the constraint in the failure message. For example, this `CHECK` constraint will prevent duplicates for the column 'MyField':

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD
   CONSTRAINT MyTable__MyField__no_dups_allowed 
      CHECK (NOT EXISTS (
                         SELECT T1.MyField 
                           FROM MyTable AS T1
                          GROUP
                             BY T1.MyField 
                         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                        ));
```

For data that fail the 'MyField' but would satisfy the other keys in the table, the failure message would be:

> One or more values are prohibited by
>   the validation rule
>   '`MyTable__MyField__no_dups_allowed`'
>   set for '`MyTable`'.  Enter a value that
>   the expression for this field can
>   accept.

You can then catch the error in your C# front end and parse the error message for the known constraint names to provide a more meaningful message.

Answer (score 0):

```
If [field name] = Me. field name in the form.Column(0) And Not Me.NewRecord Then
Me.field name in the form.Undo
Me.Undo
Exit Sub
End If

If [field name] = Me. field name in the form.Column(0) And Me.NewRecord Then
Me.field name in the form.Undo
Me.Undo
MsgBox " already there", vbInformation, "repeated"
Exit Sub
End If
```